# Optimization of multivariable quadratic equation in R subject to constraints

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

I am running on R 3.0. I have a quadratic function like:

```
2*x[1]*x[1] -5 * x[1] + 8 * x[2] * x[2] - 7*x[3]*x[2] -5 * x[3] * x[3]..
```

The function has various quadratic terms and has some linear constraints such as:

```
1 <= x[1] <= 7
-2 <= x[2] <= 9
0 <= x[3] <= 32
```

Additionally,

```
 x[1]+ x[2]+ x[3] = 100
```

Which package in R should I look at to solve this kind of an optimization problem? It is a large equation with many inequalities and I am running R 3.0.Can some thing like:

```
   x[1]+ x[2]+ x[3] = 100
```

be done with optim?

I am somehow not able to figure out how to pass parameters to constrOptim or solve.QP in quadprog.

Comment: Give us a reproductible example and it will be easier to answer with code on how to use solve.QP for example

Answer (score 3):

Both `quadprod::solve.QP` or `limSolve::lsei` will solve `QP`s with linear constraints. They differ in the way the objective is formulated:

1. min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b) for `solve.QP`
2. min(||Ax-b||^2) for `lsei`

Looking at the way you wrote your objective function, `solve.QP` sounds like the best choice, but note that you will have to rewrite your problem in matrix form.

**Edit**: I had not realized that your objective function was not convex (put differently, the matrix `D` above is not positive definite) which is a requirement for these solvers. So yes, you should rely on a non-linear solver like `optim`, but a more general one that allows for added linear constraints: `constrOptim` seems to be one of them.

Comment: Won't optim just do this for me? Or is there a problem in just using optim for this?

Comment: Give `optim` a try if you like, it might also work (maybe not as fast). The solvers I mentioned are specifically designed for solving your type of problem (quadratic programming) though.

Comment: You have edited your question. So far your "linear constraints" were really just variable bounds, which `optim` can handle. Now it looks like you have "real" linear constraints which `optim` does not handle. There might be similar tools to `optim` that also handle linear constraints, but really if I were you I wouldn't waste my time with them: just use a QP solver like the two I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Minimize[{2*x1^2 - 5*x1 + 8*x2^2 - 7*x3*x2 - 5*x3^2, 
  1 <= x1 <= 7 && -2 <= x2 <= 9 && 0 <= x3 <= 32}, {x1, x2, x3}]
Optimal value:-51929/8
Optimal vector:(x1 -> 5/4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 32)
Then, Convex Quadratic Programming Problem is sloved by improved Simplex method.

Comment: What is that, Mathematica? OP is asking about how to solve this problem in R.